# Remove the object of a specific index in a JSON array without leaving "null" behind (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a local JSON file under the path `static/json/test.json`. Its content is `[{"id": 12}, {"id": 44}]`. I want to read it, delete the object of the index `i` from it and rewrite the file so if for example `i = 0` the new content should be `[{"id": 44}]`.

What i have tried so far:

```
let i = 0;

fs.readFile("static/json/test.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(data); // obj is now [{"id": 12}, {"id": 44}]
    delete obj[i];
    fs.writeFile("static/json/test.json", JSON.stringify(obj), "utf8");
    // test.json should now be [{"id": 44}], but its [null, {"id": 44}]
});
```

If I do this, the content of test.json isn't `[{"id": 44}]`, it's `[null, {"id": 44}]`.

I've read about using `obj.splice(i, 1);` instead of `delete obj[i];`, but for some reason that doesnt do anything, without me recieving any errors.

How do I remove the object of index `i` of this JSON array without leaving `null` behind?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the fast answers! Typically `obj.splice(i, 1);` should work, the cause why it doesn't for me has to have to do with my setup. The working answer for me is

```
let i = 0;

fs.readFile("static/json/test.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(data); // obj is now [{"id": 12}, {"id": 44}]

    delete obj[i];
    obj = obj.filter(item => item);

    fs.writeFile("static/json/test.json", JSON.stringify(obj), "utf8");
    // test.json is now [{"id": 44}]
});
```

Comment: Using the code you show here with `obj.splice(i, 1)` instead of `delete obj[i]` works perfectly fine and results in `test.json` to be `[{"id":44}]`. There must be an other problem with your setup that should be fixed instead of looking for a workaround. What is the console output when you write  `obj.splice(i, 1); console.dir(JSON.stringify(obj));` instead of `delete obj[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `delete` and filter out `undefined`

```js
const obj= [{"id": 12}, {"id": 44}]
delete obj[0];
console.log(obj.filter(item => item));
```

**BUT** `splice()` works OK

```js
const obj= [{"id": 12}, {"id": 44}]
obj.splice(0, 1);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: If you're filtering, why bother with delete?

Comment: Yes I agree, only filter will do the trick. But as OP used already `delete`, So I just do the `undefined` filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.splice to do this

```js
// The item index to remove
let index = 0;
let arr = [{id: 12}, {id: 44}];
arr.splice(index,1);
console.log("Array after removing item", arr);
```